# iOS 15.2 bug on didFinish utterance callback

Tags: swift, xcode, text-to-speech, ios15, ios15.2

On iOS 15.2, the callback function `func speechSynthesizer(_ synthesizer: AVSpeechSynthesizer, didFinish utterance: AVSpeechUtterance)` is called rightly when an audio utterance completes and ends BUT it is also called (wrongly) when an audio utterance is stopped with `synthesizer.stopSpeaking(at: .immediate)`.

I confirmed this wrong behaviour compiling and simulating on Xcode 13.2.1: on all text-to-speech audio utterances stopped with `synthesizer.stopSpeaking(at: .immediate)`, the `didFinish` utterance callback function is wrongly called and shows up on the Xcode console.

On iOS 12, 13 and 14 this works fine: the stopping of an audio utterance does not call the `didFinish` utterance callback function.

Anyone as seen this behaviour on iOS 15?

Comment: If you've found a bug, please report it to Apple.

Comment: I have the same issue. `didFinish` is call on .stopSpeaking(. It's really annoying as it messes my mechanic that move from one section to the next

Comment: @tolbard Thank you for your feedback. I've reported to Apple 3 days ago but have not received feedback yet. Meanwhile I coded a workaround such that if iOS>= 15 then a different section of code is run and a flag tells me if the user stopped the utterance manually; it's working fine but I will have to revert to the original code if/when Apple corrects this bug.